# Convert any time value to hh:mm:ss.ttt format

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a string variable as follows
string date = "30/07/2014 18:28:01.000"; 
Now i want to convert this string variable to datetime variable with the same date and time format and values.Can anyone help?

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a format. Format is only important for going from `string` to `DateTime` and vice versa. Ergo, you parse the string with `DateTime.Parse` or `ParseExact`, and "restore" the format as needed when outputting the `DateTime` with `ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's the most obvious method, `DateTime.ParseExact()`. It takes a string representation of the data, a string letting it know what format the date is in, and the culture provider.

```
string date = "30/07/2014 18:28:01.000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you then wanted to convert back to a string with the same format, try this:

```
string date2=dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Remember, `DateTime` has no format itself. Only string representations of a date and/or time have a format, and therefore it's important to provide a format string when converting to/from a string.

This question could have been solved with a simple glance at the documentation.

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1, `DateTime.ParseExact` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` are the best solution.

Comment: I have tries your method but it gives me time in 12 hour format but i need them in the exact format that is present in string ie. 24 hr format

Comment: @user3024200 What do you mean it gives you time in 12 hour format? Please provide your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your given method gives me error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: it gives me "30/07/2014 6:28:01 PM" but i need "30/07/2014 18:28:01" as i told the exact format and values present in string

Comment: @user3024200 a DateTime is *not* a string, this is why we're trying to get the code that you're seeing a "PM" for.  If you do just DateTime.ToString(), that may not give you the format you desire, but using a format such as .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")  If you provide your code and how you're arriving at a "PM" we might be better able to assist

Comment: @user3024200 As Kriteneter and Luaan have explained, DateTime has no inherent format. Your question is regarding how to convert a string (with a certain format) to a DateTime, not how to convert a DateTime to a string with a certain format. In both cases, use a format string to specify what format to convert from/to because *DateTime has no internal format*. The internal representation of a DateTime is the number of ticks since some arbitrary date, therefore it only has a format when you convert to a string using one of the overloaded `.ToString()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can try injecting a DateTimeFormatInfo object to tell the TryParse method to translate the date correctly

```
        string date = "30/07/2014 18:28:01.000";
        DateTime newDate;

        var fp = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
        fp.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        DateTime.TryParse(date, fp, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
            out newDate);
```

Comment: Why would one choose to use this over [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, TryParse doesnt throw an exception if the date string is invalid, ParseExact will throw an InvalidFormatException

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I asked why someone would use `TryParse` instead of `TryParseExact` when dealing with a custom format string. Not `TryParse` vs `ParseExact`.

Comment: Oh sorry, should have read more carefully. Seriously I don't know. If the date string "dd/MM/yyyy" is provided as input to the TryParseExact method it will not be able to parse the date, it's a bit more picky hence the "Exact"-part of the method name. On the other hand it seems like there's a lot more going on under the hood in the TryParse method, which should make it significantly slower. Maybe someone else has a good clean anser on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
string date = "30/07/2014 18:28:01.000";

DateTime yourConvertedDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

format only really makes a difference (i think) when parsing to string.  You can add your format at that point like:

```
string str = yourConvertedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

as an example.

Comment: Format makes a difference when converting to DateTime also, depending on the format the data is in. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, you're missing a semicolon.

Comment: I have tried your method but it gives me time in 12 hour format but i need them in the exact format that is present in string ie. 24 hr format

Comment: @user3024200 I'm not sure what you mean about the 12 hour format, are you referring to the dateTime object itself, or the string parse of the datetime object?  The DateTime is a representation of the DateTime where format doesn't matter, you can have it printed out in whatever format you'd like with the .ToString("provide your format")

Comment: what i mean is DateTime.Parse(date) gives me "30/07/2014 6:28:01 PM" but i need "30/07/2014 18:28:01"

Comment: @mason sorry I'm not sitting in front of a compiler.  Additionally, since his dates are in a non standard (at least to the US) format, I was assuming that his date format was native for his culture, in which case you do not need to specify a format correct?  Maybe a bad assumption on my part but anyway I upvoted your answer since you seem to know a bit more about what you're talking about than i do :P

Comment: It uses the culture specified for the thread, which may or may not match the format he's trying to parse. In *all* of my applications, I use `ParseExact` instead of `Parse` so that it's not ambiguous what format I'm expecting.